# Get binding literal value

Tags: angular, angular6

Is it possible to get literal value of [(ngModel)] (or any other binding) in Angular 6?

Example bellow should return "foo.bar":

```
<test label="Status" [(ngModel)]="foo.bar"></test>
```

**Update**

Binding should be working, so wrapping *foo.bar* into quotes is not an option.

Comment: AFAIK no, there is no way of knowing the literal name of a bounded property.

Comment: When and how? Do you want to read it inside your running application?

Comment: Inside running application in component itself (constructor or ngOnInit for example)... If compiler wouldn't remove attributes I could get it through ElementRef).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this workaround:

```
<test label="Status" [(ngModel)]="foo.bar" data-lit-value="foo.bar"></test>
```